# Hive Avro recalling field just written out

Tags: hadoop, hive, avro

I am using HIVE and attempting to write out to a table and would like to know if it's possible to recall a field that I just wrote out to in order to create another field variable.

```
Case When Substr(Upper(Trim(MBRCHR)),-3) rlike '[8-9][0-9][A-E]'
    Then
        Substr(Upper(trim(regexp_replace(MBRCHR,'[^0-9]',''))),1,Length(Upper(Trim(regexp_replace(MBRCHR,'[^0-9]',''))))-2)
    Else
        Upper(trim(regexp_replace(MBRCHR,'[^0-9]+','')))
    End as MBR_DRVD,
Case when Length(MBR_DRVD) between 7 and 9
    Then ***** use this to derive the new field.
```

I have tried writing it as such but because MBR_DRVD is not in the table that I am populating the current table from, it errors out.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

not possible to do it directly, you can do it using a subquery like

```
select ....
Case when Length(MBR_DRVD) between 7 and 9
        Then ***** use this to derive the new field.
from (
select 
Case When Substr(Upper(Trim(MBRCHR)),-3) rlike '[8-9][0-9][A-E]'
    Then
        Substr(Upper(trim(regexp_replace(MBRCHR,'[^0-9]',''))),1,Length(Upper(Trim(regexp_replace(MBRCHR,'[^0-9]',''))))-2)
    Else
        Upper(trim(regexp_replace(MBRCHR,'[^0-9]+','')))
    End as MBR_DRVD,
...
from yourtable
) t;
```